# Скрыть иконку поиска когда поле для ввода в фокусе

Tags: css, display

Нужно скрыть иконку в поле поиска когда само поле в фокусе.

```
<div class="news__search--form">
<input type="text" placeholder="Ich suche...">
</div>
```

Она установлена с помощью псевдо :after для класса - news__search--form.
Если возможно без Js

Comment: Было бы замечательно, если бы Вы прикрепили CSS-код

Comment: какую иконку? я ничего не вижу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `z-index`:

```css
.news__search--form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.news__search--form::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  right: 6px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.news__search--form input {
  position: relative;
}

.news__search--form input:focus {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="news__search--form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ich suche...">
</div>
```

Comment: Толково придумано! )

Answer (score 1):

@barmaley, на css такое нельзя сделать, т.к. плейсхолдер это свойство `input`, а иконка принадлежит его родителю. Лучше будет сделать ее не через `::after`, а обычным тегом, расположенным внутри `div`, после `input`, чтобы появилась возможность написать для нее селектор зависящий от состояния `input`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.parent input {
  font-size: 160%;
  padding: .4em;
}

.parent svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: .4em;
  fill: #888;
}

.parent input:focus~svg {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск...">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M23.822 20.88l-6.353-6.354c.93-1.465 1.467-3.2 1.467-5.059.001-5.219-4.247-9.467-9.468-9.467s-9.468 4.248-9.468 9.468c0 5.221 4.247 9.469 9.468 9.469 1.768 0 3.421-.487 4.839-1.333l6.396 6.396 3.119-3.12zm-20.294-11.412c0-3.273 2.665-5.938 5.939-5.938 3.275 0 5.94 2.664 5.94 5.938 0 3.275-2.665 5.939-5.94 5.939-3.274 0-5.939-2.664-5.939-5.939z"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Возможно. 2. Почему тегом лучше? 3. Что за шаманство с transform?

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. Забыл про `:focus-within`. 2. Потому что забыл. 3. В смысле? Стандартная практика центрования. Вместо margin'а. Такой способ лучше т.к. не нужно знать размер элемента.

Comment: 2. Ещё через фон инпута можно. Тег мне как-то меньше всего нравится. 3. А, точно. Что-то невнимательно смотрел. Только у неё есть косяк - если размер нечётный, может заблюриться.

Answer (score 1):

Если позволяет поддержка браузерами, то можно использовать `:focus-within`:

```css
.news__search--form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.news__search--form::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  right: 6px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.news__search--form:focus-within::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="news__search--form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Ich suche...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать иконку, как фон для label, и уже его показывать/прятать

```css
input{
  position: relative;
}

label{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

input:focus~label{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="news__search--form">
  <input type="text" id="icon" placeholder="Ich suche...">
  <label for="icon"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: `label` - это хорошо, но лучше всё же вешать `pointer-events: none` - различие будет при попытке кликнуть сразу правой кнопкой (например, ПКМ -> вставить для инпута).